# Responsive Css: Fixed Left Sidebar and Footer conflict in small screens

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I need your help about this complex problem.

I have fixed header,left Sidebar and absolute sticky footer, and if the content height is smaller than browser's height, no scrolls are visible.

Html

```
<header></header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="aside-left">
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
        <p>sdfsdfs</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container-mid"></div>
    <div class="push"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Css

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background:#ffaaaa;
    margin:0;
}
header {
    background: #2f3d4c;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 600;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}
.container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.aside-left {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 75px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 192px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
}
.container-mid {
    margin-left: 192px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}
.push, footer {
    height: 55px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    background: #2f3d4c;
    z-index: 100;
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 690px) {
    .aside--left {
        position: absolute;
        margin-bottom: -75px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: -100%;
    }
}
```

Everything is ok in large screens, but when  screen height is smaller, and the content of Left Sidebar is higher than container height, footer is overlapping Left Sidebar's content and some part of it is not visible (See the fiddle).

I need this to work also in IE8+ and keep absolute position for left Sidebar when browser height is small, so that left sidebar will be strached from top to bottom (as I did in media query).
Solution can include JS too, no matter.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/frontDev111/dqd2f2dt/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right you're trying to achieve something like this.
I fixed the footer with `position: fixed` and added `overflow: auto` (to show scrollbars if needed since you hid them) as well as `bottom: 55px` (footer-height) to your left sidebar.

http://jsfiddle.net/dqd2f2dt/4/

(I filled it with testdata content to test how the content itself does its job)
I tested this with IE9 and it worked properly.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I don't need scrollbars in Left SideBar, I need container height to be strached when left Sidebar height is more than screen height

Comment: Hmm, so what if you just add a `position: fixed` to your footer within your first fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/dqd2f2dt/5/)

Comment: That's not what I need, footer should be absolute))

Comment: Could you exactly describe what you're trying to achieve? Maybe tell me exactly what every element should do while resizing your browser since I don't understand it properly.